# Passing Parameter to struts2 component

Tags: templates, struts2, components, freemarker

I am attempting to create a struts2 component using freemarker. I created an `ftl` file with code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${parameters.library?default('')}"></script>
```

Which is expecting a parameter named `library` to be passed to the component. If the parameter is absent then it defaults to a blank `String`.

On my JSP page, I am referring to the component like this:

```
<s:component template="mytemplate.ftl">
    <s:param name="library" value="/scripts/mylibrary.js"/>
</s:component>
```

Unfortunately, the value for the library parameter is not being set. It is always a blank `String`.

I am using the advice from this [tutorial](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_ui_component) and it seems as if the `s:param` tag should pass the parameter into the template and make it available. What am I missing here?

Does anyone have some experience building these components that could shed some light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

send the param with single quotes

```
<s:component template="mytemplate.ftl">
    <s:param name="library" value="'/scripts/mylibrary.js'"/>
</s:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ran across some syntax in the docs that works. I have to refer to the parameter like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${parameters.get('library')?default('')}">
</script>
```